# What is difference between stock CDI and racing CDI in a 4 stroke motorcycle?

Tags: four-stroke, cdi

The mechanic told me that stock CDI has a limit after certain speed but the local one has none hence increase in speed. While searching for that I came across this keyword of Racing CDI and become curious.

Comment: CDI= Capacitive Discharge Ignition

Answer (score 2):

A CDI ignition system uses capacitors to charge up the energy for the spark plug discharge. Generally speaking, capacitors do this more quickly than electrical coils, allowing the ignition system to recharge more quickly for another cycle, meaning you can achieve higher RPMs.

That being said, not all capacitors are the same, and some charge more quickly than others. The ones that charge more quickly will allow even higher RPMs, if your engine can handle it, whereas capacitor that charge more slowly would need more time between cycles, meaning lower max RPMs.

The stock CDI would have slower charging capacitors with a lower max RPM, while "racing" CDI would have faster charging capacitors and a higher max RPM.

You won't notice a difference at all unless you push the engine to the rev limit, assuming your engine can reach the higher rev limit allowed by a "racing" CDI.

Comment: While i completely agree with with your final conclusion, the limiting capability of CDIs being capacitors is incorrect. CDIs use high voltage to fire the coil. Something in the neighborhood of 100 to 200 volts. Inside the CID is a DC to DC converter that steps up battery voltage to the needed amount. It is the size and quality of the DC to DC that tends to be the limiting factor. Also the size and recovery time of the trigger element that releases the capacitors into the coil also plays a role in capability.